# How to show alert after javascript redirecting?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

How can I show alert after redirecting?

```
def index
    respond_to do |format|
      if user_signed_in?
        format.js
      else
        format.js {render :js => "window.location = #{code_path.to_json}"}
      end
    end
  end
```

index.js.erb

```
window.location = '/cabinet';
alert('hey');
```

Comment: You should out the `alert()` in the `/cabinet` page. After redirecting you cannot do anything.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is is possible to call a function after window.location has loaded new URL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7493847/is-is-possible-to-call-a-function-after-window-location-has-loaded-new-url)

Comment: maybe you need to set some flag, either in query string or browser storage

Comment: What about using onbeforeunload event?! That's kind of its purpose

Answer (score 0):

write your alert message in document.ready function in /cabinet page.

> `$( document ).ready(function() { 
>         alert( "ready!" );
>    });`

Comment: Ok, Also, I think I need to set some flag in index action

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use alert followed by the window.location as the state is moved to new page. However you can show the alert() in the new page which in your case is '/cabinet' as follows,

if you are using JQuery,

```
$(function(){
    alert("hey");
});
```

or

```
<body onload="alert('hey');">
```